# How to read .sql file & support CRUD operations using javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql

I am working on phonegap Android platform. I have mydatabase.sql file in assets folder. I dont know how to deal with that sql file. basically i have to load this sql file using javascript. 
here is some data which is in mydatabase.sql:

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

CREATE TABLE `media` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Part` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `No` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Title_EN` varchar(100) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `Year` int(24) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Id`)
  \\
  \\another values
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=649 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `media`
--

INSERT INTO `media` (`Id`, `Part`, `No`, `Title_Hari`, `Type`,  `Artist_EN`,  `Track`, `Year`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1,  'Sant Sangeet' 'Cassette', NULL, NULL, NULL, 7, NULL),
 \\
 \\
 \\ another values

CREATE TABLE `media1` (

 \\ create another table

INSERT INTO `media1`

 \\ insert data 
 \\ 
 \\
```

mydatabase.sql contains create table methods & insert value to that tables.

tried some methods in js:

Demo.JS:

```
var db;

function ReadFile() {
    console.log("call database");
    try
    {
        if (window.openDatabase)
        {

            db = openDatabase("../sql/mydatabase.sql", "1.0", " Database", 200000);
            console.log("open database");
            db.transaction (function (transaction) 

                    {
                console.log("transaction database");


                            var sql = "SELECT * FROM media";

                            transaction.executeSql (sql, undefined, 

                            function (transaction, result)

                            {

                                alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

                            },  function(error){
                                console.log("error");
                            });

                    });
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("else database");
            // Handle no database support
        }
    }
    catch(err)
    { 
        console.log("error database");
        // Handle error
    }
}
```

OutPut:

```
  call database
  open database
  transaction database
  no such a tabke media
  error
```

So my problem is how to import it in my app or how to deal with this sql database & after importing this database, how to perform CRUD operations & pass the query to this. Please suggest some Tutorial. Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks.

Comment: You want to but able to execute SQL queries on your DB server using javascript ?

Comment: As @Brewal says, this is not a common use case - but can always see what the node.js does..

Comment: That's not even that it is not common, this would be a severe security breach if we could do this. You have to ask your server for something and then let it do the job of asking the DB. Basicly, this could be done with some ajax and php.

Comment: @Brewal So what is the best way to use DB? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: you want to connect to your database from your server, not from each client. each client can then connect to the server requesting data..

Comment: @Brewal I want to implement offline database with huge amount of data & data is fixed.so how can i achieve with this local mydatabase.sql file ?

Comment: You will have to store the data locally and then sync it when the user is connected. Just to make sure, we are talking about a database that is common to all users don't we ?

Comment: @Brewal can you show some code? want to use this  mydatabase.sql file. check my edited question .

Comment: Wow, ok... So you are trying to create a local database. One for each user, not one for all the users ! Are we ok with that ? I mean, the data is only saved on the phone of the user ?

Comment: @Brewal yes the data will only saved on the phone of the user.

Comment: Ok, so forget every single thing of what was said above... I'll try to make an answer.

Comment: @Brewal Thanks.Take your time. will appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, I tried to make this clear. The fact that we thought it was for a server-side database was the presence of `ENGINE=InnoDB` in your sql file. Where did you get this file ?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. A text file with some DDL code is **not** a database. You cannot issue SQL queries against a text file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the content of your `SQL` file using **ajax** and then execute it as a query. But what you are doing wrong here is that you try to create a database from a file, but you can't.
The `openDatabase` object waits for those parameters :

- Database name
- Version number
- Text description
- Size of database
- Creation callback

You can't pass the file path to the first parameter. This is just the name of the database. So keep it simple :

```
db = openDatabase("mydb", "1.0", " Database description", 200000);
```

Then you have two options. The one I first described using `ajax` and the easy one to understand that consists of putting your queries directly into your `javascript` file :

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {  
   tx.executeSql(
       'CREATE TABLE `media` (
           `Id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
           `Part` int(11) NOT NULL,
           \\ other values
       )
   ');
});
```

Note : forget about `ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ...`. That's for server-side database.

Or with **ajax** (using `jQuery` i.e.) :

```
$.get("../sql/mydatabase.sql", function(content) {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {  
        tx.executeSql(content);
    });
});
```

See : **[jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)**

Comment: Thanx for your answer. As m totally newbie to javascript sql its very difficult for me. will use db.transaction method.how to perform Query in this db? can u suggest some tutorial or hint for query?

Comment: There's a good tutorial [here](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/) or [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm)

Comment: have tried Ajax. to use it, i have to init db. how to init it?

Comment: Init it before your ajax call with `openDatabase`

Comment: Thanx.is there any tool which create sql database & fire the query where i can get the actual statement as statements from my file giving error in javascript.